# differencing by group with dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to created a 7 day lag difference by group. So, I am trying to replicate the code below and hope to get a similar result with a 7 day lag instead.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(dx=c(NA, diff(x)), dy=c(NA, diff(y)))

   x y dx dy
 1 5 3 NA NA
 2 8 9  3  6
 3 3 1 -5 -8
 4 1 5 -2  4
```

But I am getting the error messages:

> Error: incompatible size (900), expecting 905 (the group size) or 1

is there a quick and easy way to fix this error. I undertstand it might have to do with mutate

Comment: Please show your input example.  Based on the output, there is no `colname1, colname2`

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: thanks for the comment. The only difference between my code and the one above is the group_by. 
so  dat %>% group_by(anything) %>% mutate(dx=c(NA, diff(x)), dy=c(NA, diff(y))). I know it is an easy fix, I just don't know how to fix it since I am fairly new to r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pad with `NA` for the number of days in your lag. Just as you need 1 `NA` to pad for the lack of a difference value for the first row with a lag of 1, now you need 7 `NA` to pad for the lack of a difference value for the first 7 rows. Example with built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(dx = c(NA, diff(mpg)),
         dx7 = c(rep(NA,7), diff(mpg, 7)))
```

Or with grouping:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>%
  mutate(dx = c(NA, diff(mpg)),
         dx7 = c(rep(NA,7), diff(mpg, 7)))
```

@Axeman's nice answer reminded me that you can also use the `zoo` package's version of `diff`, which has built-in padding. You just have to convert your vector to a `zoo` object so that the `diff.zoo` method will get dispatched, instead of base R `diff`, making `na.pad` available:

```
library(zoo) 

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(dx = diff(zoo(mpg), na.pad=TRUE),
         dx7 = diff(zoo(mpg), 7, na.pad=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting rid of the `diff` altogether, and use `dplyr`s very own `lag`. This takes care of the needed `NA`'s.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(dx = mpg - lag(mpg),
         dx7 = mpg - lag(mpg, 7))
```

Comment: Well, I've learned quite a bit from your answers the last year or so.

Comment: Thanks! That's nice to know.